# Create heatmap based on Polygon with leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to make a heatmap with leaflet based on Polygons data. The data used is basic shapeFile data containing population densities for the Netherlands.

Since the size and shapes from all the polygons differ, the `addHeatmap()` function from the leaflet library doesn't give the right result although I would like the visuals to be similar.

My very basic code:

```
xy <- spTransform(shpFile, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
leaflet(xy) %>%
 addTiles() %>%
 addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(as.numeric(bev_dichth)),
             weight = 1,
             opacity = 1,
             color = "white",
             dashArray = "3",
             fillOpacity = 0.7)
```

With shpFile being the dutch shapeFile data downloaded from the [here](https://www.cbs.nl/nl-nl/dossier/nederland-regionaal/geografische%20data/wijk-en-buurtkaart-2011).

I would like my output to be like the left picture instead of the right but avoid using coordinates since the shapes of the Polygons are different.
[Example picture can be found here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Heat-map-of-the-cross-sectional-study-participants-residence-versus-population-density_fig1_282122727).

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to use leaflet extensions, examples: https://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-heatmap

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the solutions provided here are based on coordinates rather than polygons. Or am I missing something?